# AngularJS filter in config

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm using the following plugins [angular-translate](https://github.com/angular-translate/angular-translate) and [ng-breadcrumbs](https://github.com/ianwalter/ng-breadcrumbs)

both are configured in the config, but how would one make it that the labels can be translated?

I could do it in the controller on each page, but isn't there an easier way?

config:

```
someApp.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', '$translateProvider',
    function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider, $translateProvider) {
        $translateProvider.useStaticFilesLoader({
            prefix: '/localization/locale-',
            suffix: '.json'
        });
        $translateProvider.preferredLanguage('nl');

        $routeProvider.
        when('/', {
            templateUrl: 'partials/landing.html',
            controller: 'HomeCtrl',
            label: 'Home'
        }).
            // default
        otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/'
        });
    }
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about label, but templateUrl can be replaced by templateProvider which is a function that returns a string.

You can try to write a function on label, giving labels in different languages upon a condition (it can even be a rest call).

Comment: that seems a bit overkill, I just added the filter in the ng-breadcrumbs plugin on the label :)

Comment: right, you use an add-on, there must be something built in to manage this :)

Comment: Found an other sollution

Answer (score 0):

there was an easy way to solve this, I wasn't so awake apparently:
by adding `|translate` to the `ng-bind` the problem was solved

```
<ul id="breadcrumb">
    <li ng-repeat="breadcrumb in breadcrumbs.get() track by breadcrumb.path" ng-class="{ active: $last }">
        <a ng-if="!$last" ng-href="#{{ breadcrumb.path }}" ng-bind="breadcrumb.label | translate" class="margin-right-xs">
        </a><span ng-if="$last" ng-bind="breadcrumb.label | translate"></span>
    </li>
</ul>
```